# grep a particular string and print one column before match

Tags: bash, grep

I need to print the value of one column left after matching Protectedfor52weeks  or Protectedfor365days. Below is my line

```
completed Protectedfor52weeks failed Protectedfor365days
```

For above line desired output is as below

```
completed failed
```

Comment: The easy answer is to read the line into an array e.g. `line="completed Protectedfor52weeks failed Protectedfor365days"; array=( $line ); for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do if [[ (${array[i]} == Protectedfor52weeks || ${array[i]} == Protectedfor365days) && i -lt $((${#array[@]} - 1)) ]]; then echo ${array[$((i+1))]}; fi; done`

Comment: is it always in the same order, `Protectedfor52weeks` goes first, then `Protectedfor365days` ?

Comment: When you do not really need to have "completed" and "failed" on the same line, you could use `grep -Eo "[^ ]* Protectedfor(52weeks|365days)" x2 | cut -d" " -f1`. This will skip matches when the particular string (Protectedfor52weeks) is the first word on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep with lookahead

```
grep -oP '\S+\s(?=Protectedfor(52weeks|365days))' file
```

check either or both matches on all lines.

Comment: Now I like that solution (even though it requires POSIX regex).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin did you mean `-P` as POSIX? because `-P` means using `PCRE` regex.. or you were highlighting something else?

Comment: Yes, my bad, Perl Compatible Regular Expression `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, while you can do it with `grep` and **extended regex** matching, or with `sed` and a **back reference**, the easy way is to read it into an array, and simply test as you iterate over the array:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="completed Protectedfor52weeks failed Protectedfor365days"

array=( $line )

for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do 
    if [[ (${array[i]} == Protectedfor52weeks || \
    ${array[i]} == Protectedfor365days) && \
    $i -lt $((${#array[@]} - 1)) ]]; then 
        echo ${array[$((i+1))]}
    fi
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash weeks.sh
failed
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`; iterating over the fields and printing the field before any of the desired words:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^Protectedfor(52weeks|365days)$/) print $(i-1)}'
```

**Example:**

```
% awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^Protectedfor(52weeks|365days)$/) print $(i-1)}' <<<'completed Protectedfor52weeks failed Protectedfor365days'
completed
failed
```